# Build deb package with more recent cmake on launchpad

Tags: ppa, deb, packaging, launchpad

I created a library that I'd like to share via deb packages in a ppa.

I'd like to support from ubuntu 20.04 but I need a more recent version of cmake to build the library, and I'm wondering what would be the best way to do it.

Is it possible to use a cmake from another ppa in build-depends?

If not, should I locally build a more recent cmake in the rules file and use it?

Or should I make a recent cmake package in my ppa and use it for building the package of my library?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the lib on github if so can you post the link

Comment: also this may help https://wiki.debian.org/SimplePackagingTutorial

Comment: My lib is available here : https://github.com/RandomPrototypes/libQuestMR
but my problem comes from a dependency of the lib : onnx-runtime ( https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime ). onnx-runtime is only available as source or precompiled zip, not as a package. So I want to package it in my ppa and put it as dependency of my lib.

Comment: ok can you provide a list of build dependencies for ubuntu so like cmake or etc. use https://packages.ubuntu.com to find the deb names note innor onnxruntime for now

Comment: i just use https://wiki.debian.org/SimplePackagingTutorial to package buffered socket, and it was easy so you do it

Comment: So what I have gathered is that you are busy, and you have a lot of packages, so make them up to the Debian spec first so https://wiki.debian.org/SimplePackagingTutorial

Comment: I asked ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com to make an onnx runtime package.

Comment: thanks
I already packaged BufferedSocket and RPCameraInterface on https://launchpad.net/~random-prototypes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  I only need onnx-runtime package and then I can easily manage to package libQuestMR. I think cuda version of onnx-runtime may be difficult to create so maybe I could start with the cpu version and leave the option of manually installing it for cuda version.